# When did area51 become a beta site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, icons

I noticed today in [my profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227817/tijesunimi) that area51's icon under my accounts is now like that of a beta site

[image]

I have been able to reproduce this accross other people's profile on meta and other SE sites. Example [Madara Uchiha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/27/madara-uchiha).

Also its the same in the top bar

[image]

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Ohhh, when did they switch to a big ole sprite image? Looks like someone forgot to add the background position coordinates for Area 51, so it's going to the first icon in the sprite.

Comment: In the [full accounts list](http://stackexchange.com/users/2929219/tijesunimi?tab=accounts) it's OK.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes

Comment: @animuson good catch! Go figure. ;)

Comment: I took a peek at [the site icon sprites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png) - now I want to know what [this one is](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PEBuE.png)!

Comment: @animuson the sprite is a change we made this morning, to reduce bandwidth and HTTP requests in the new topbar...and maybe some retina love later this week.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We felt it just wasn't really working out.  We *tried* to get answers to all your questions but you *just*. *kept*. *asking*.  We've decided to put the network into beta status indefinitely.  It's been a good runs guys, but, well, you know how it goes.

Or it could be fixed in a build rolling out now, either or.

Comment: It's probably both.

Comment: So those of us who came late to the party finally get a shot at those previously unattainable Beta badges?!?!?!

Comment: [mobile theme is crying for help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209909/152859) now. :)