# Site icons missing in mobile theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web, icons

The icons for various Stack Exchange sites seem to have disappeared in the mobile theme, in user profile summary tab:

> [image]

I know that the above picture lacks *freehand circles* but there used to be icons for various SO sites below accounts.

(This was observed using Firefox on Android and also on the mobile version on a desktop.)

Comment: repro on Safari and Chrome for iphone.

Comment: [No sprites for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209820/when-did-area51-become-a-beta-site#comment672135_209820)! ;)

Comment: Samo's working on this now, will be fixed in a build soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix is built out, long live the mobile *sprites*.

Comment: Thanks, it looks perfect as ever now.